# why is my canvas zoom/pan slowing down.

Tags: html, extjs, canvas, easeljs

I'm a new programmer just trying to learn how to make webpages. I found a code to zoom and pan canvas elements but when  I implemented it into an extJS window It started becoming sluggish. It doesn't become sluggish if the image I render is just a shape, only if It's from a file image. I thought at first I was creating instances of objects over and over but I tried deleting the objects after use and it didn't change anything. Why is my zooming slowing down?

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.define("w",{
width: 1000,
height: 750,
extend: "Ext.Window",
html: '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="750">'
+ 'alternate content'
+ '</canvas>'



,afterRender: function() {
this.callParent(arguments); 

var canvas= document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;   
var stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");

/*function addCircle(r,x,y){
var g=new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("#ff0000").drawCircle(0,0,r);
var s=new createjs.Shape(g)
s.x=x;
s.y=y;
stage.addChild(s);
stage.update();
}*///// If I use this function instead of loading an img there's no slowdown. 


   function setBG(){
            var myImage = new Image();
            myImage.src = "dbz.jpg";
            myImage.onload = setBG;
            var bgrd = new createjs.Bitmap(myImage);
            stage.addChild(bgrd);
            stage.update();
            delete myImage;
            delete bgrd;
            };
setBG(); 

//addCircle(40,200,100);
//addCircle(50,400,400);

canvas.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
canvas.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);

var zoom;

function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
if(Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)))>0)
    zoom=1.1;
else
    zoom=1/1.1;
stage.regX=stage.mouseX;
stage.regY=stage.mouseY;
stage.x=stage.mouseX;
stage.y=stage.mouseY;   
stage.scaleX=stage.scaleY*=zoom;

stage.update();
delete zoom; 
}


stage.addEventListener("stagemousedown", function(e) {
var offset={x:stage.x-e.stageX,y:stage.y-e.stageY};
stage.addEventListener("stagemousemove",function(ev) {
    stage.x = ev.stageX+offset.x;
    stage.y = ev.stageY+offset.y;
    stage.update();
             delete offset; 
});
stage.addEventListener("stagemouseup", function(){
    stage.removeAllEventListeners("stagemousemove");
});
}); 

} //end aferrender

}); //end define



Ext.create("w", {
autoShow: true });
}); //end onready
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are infinitely re-loading the BG image.  After your BG image finishes loading, your onload function callback just makes it call getBG again which will just repeat the same process forever.

```
function setBG() {
  ...
  myImage.onload = setBG;
  ...
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you expect by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't need to delete the image. Off the top of my head, this is how I would generally load an image for use in canvas, (based on how your train of thought is working).

```
function setBG(){
        var myImage = new Image();
        myImage.src = "dbz.jpg";
        myImage.onload = function(){
            var bgrd = new createjs.Bitmap(this);
            stage.addChild(bgrd);
            stage.update();
        }
};

setBG();
```

Comment: ohhh yeahh I see it now thanks... but I don't really need the myImage.onload = function(){ do I? I just commented out the whole myimage.onload line and it works fine enough. IS there a reason to wait for .onload?

Comment: The only reason would be in the case that you needed to do something only AFTER the image was finished loading and ready to go.

Comment: yeah I usually wait for the image to load before i try rendering it to the screen so that I can either do an effect (fade it in) or use it as a sprite sheet and slice it up. Your using createjs so im sure they handle a lot of those situations for you. Also it can be nice to use the load information to make sure things don't start before your ready for them to start... in a game for example.